# How to convert a string into a HttpFoundation\Request in Symfony?

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, request

Hello I created a POST method, at the end I get a string $body.
I want to give this string to parameter of an other POST method registerMember(Request $request) but I don't succeed to give this $body as parameter because it is not a HttpFoundation\Request as expected.

I tried both of them :

```
$send = $this->registerMember(new Request([$body]));
$send = $this->registerMember(Request::create($body));
```

No one work

Could you help me please ? Thank you !

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you are asking here.  I'd suggest looking at the actual source code for the Request object as well as registerMember.  new Request([],$post); where $post is an array of key/values might do what you want.

Comment: There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28792) about this.